# How to critically evaluate the given statement

Tags: networking, network-protocols

Statement goes as:

> There are various ways to implement a WAN, but using the PSTN is
>   usually the best.

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: What year is this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to write down different ways of implementing a LAN, their pros and cons.